# Mifare Classic 4K Authentication failed- how to make it Work?

Tags: nfc, mifare, texas-instruments

I am very new to the 14443A protocol and mifare Clasic 4k Tag. I have a TRF7960A RFID reader interfaced to my device which is supporting Mifare mode after reading the Firmware version.

I got some information from my vendor but still i am facing issue in authentication.

I have pasted the Commands send and received in below.

Can any one help me in this about how the packet is being created?

Thanks in advance

Jethin

### Set to Mifare Mode

Send : 0108000304FD00000
Returned : 108000304FD0000

### Firmware Version 3.3[Mode Mifare]

### Set Protocol

Send : 010A0003041000010000
Returned : 010A0003041000010000
Register write request.

Send : 010C00030410002101080000
Returned : 010C00030410002101080000
Register write request.

Send : 0109000304F0000000
Returned : 0109000304F0000000

Send : 0109000304F1FF0000
Returned : 0109000304F1FF0000

---

### Scan Card UID

Send : 0109000304A0010000
Returned : 0109000304A0010000
14443A REQA.
(0200)(DB24C7A69E)[DB24C7A69E]

Received UID is DB24C7A69E

---

### Authicate Block 04     Key is  FFFFFFFFFFFF  UID is DB24C7A69E

Send : 010A0003041850000000
Returned : 010A0003041850000000
Request mode.
[]

Send : 010D000304A2DB24C7A69E0000
Returned : 010D000304A2DB24C7A69E0000
14443A Select.
(0200)[18]

Send : 010E000304C0FFFFFFFFFFFF0000
Returned : 010E000304C0FFFFFFFFFFFF0000
Crypto1 set key.
Initialization ok

Send : 010F000304C16004DB24C7A69E 0000
Returned : 010F000304C16004DB24C7A69E 0000
Crypto1 authentication step 1.
!! 00 bytes and 00 bits received, expected 4 bytes and 0 bits. Abort

Send : 010C000304C23D6E98990000
Returned : 010C000304C23D6E98990000
Crypto1 authentication step 2.ý

---

### Read Block 04  DATA

Send : 010A000304C830040000
Returned : 010A000304C830040000
Encrypted request mode.
!! cipher not initialized. Abort

---

### Write Block 04  Write Data 12345678123456781234567812345678

Send : 010A000304C8A0040000

Returned : 010A000304C8A0040000
Encrypted request mode.
!! cipher not initialized. Abort

Send : 0118000304C8123456781234567812345678123456780000
Returned : 0118000304C8123456781234567812345678123456780000
Encrypted request mode.
!! cipher not initialized. Abort

Answer (score 0):

A MIFARE Classic UID is always 4 bytes or 7 bytes, never 5 bytes. I don't know the TRF7960A, but I suspect that your problem is related to this. It would make the authentication fail: the tag will simply not answer. Any following commands requiring a successful authentication will also not work.